# IE8 JavaScript: select.options behaviour

Tags: javascript, dom, internet-explorer-8, language-implementation

I've today discovered some strange behaviour in IE8's implementation of the DOM select element's JavaScript 'options' property.

Given the following HTML:

```
<select id="sel"><option value="val">An option</option></select>
```

And the javascript:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('sel');
alert(sel === sel.options); //alerts 'true' in IE8
```

Obviously, the clever fellow writing the select implementation on IE8 has written an indexer on the select element, and then had it expose itself as its own 'options' property to JavaScript.

**My question is**: is this expected functionality, according to the JavaScript language spec? Is this a known bug? Should I continue to treat the 'options' property as an object, rather than specifically an Array?

This is not how the select DOM element behaves under Firefox 3.5, Chrome 1.0, or Safari 3.1, where the 'options' property is exposed as a JavaScript array...

*For reference, I came across this when I passed the 'options' property to the jQuery constructor in order to wrap its elements. Rather than the expected result of a jQuery object with X elements (as occured using Firefox, Chrome and Safari), I was returned a jQuery object with 1 element (the select element itself).*

Comment: It is the same behavior in IE7 also. But alerts false in FF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is not related to JavaScript language, but rather to DOM :)

Nitpicking aside, DOM L2, for example, defines [`HTMLSelectElement`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-94282980) as an object having `options` property. That property is defined to be of type [`HTMLOptionsCollection`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#HTMLOptionsCollection) and represents - "The collection of OPTION elements contained by this element."

Now, to quote `HTMLOptionsCollection`:

> An HTMLOptionsCollection is a list of
>   nodes representing HTML option
>   element. An individual node may be
>   accessed by either ordinal index or
>   the node's name or id attributes.
>
> Note: Collections in the HTML DOM are
>   assumed to be live meaning that they
>   are automatically updated when the
>   underlying document is changed.

Technically, there's **nothing preventing** `HTMLSelectElement` being equal to its `HTMLOptionsCollection` (not in DOM L2 specs, at least). Implementation is fully compliant as long as it matches standard behavior (i.e. elements are accessible by index or name/id and interface properties/methods - such as `item` and `length` - are implemented as specified).

Frankly, I don't see why you would care about this peculiarity. If accessing elements by index/name works, it shouldn't matter what `options` is equal to. As always, best bet is to design scripts in standard-compliant manner (and only then work around any known deficiencies).

Comment: What I find interesting is that under IE8's JavaScript DOM API (and ONLY IE8's API) the .options collection does not behave like an array (even though you can access it by index).

This is a simple difference to work around, but it is yet another difference between JS APIs that seems entirely unnecessary.

I submit some code. Run under IE8, it yields 'true', 'true'. Would this not be undefined behaviour?

//where 'elem' is a select element
var elem = document.getElementById('id');

alert(elem[1] === elem.options[1]);
alert(elem === elem.options.options);